# Trying to solve increment a double list in python by an index

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to solve this problem.This is leet code 1252.
Basically you have a matrix and index. 
Say you have a matrix

```
                     0 0 0
                     0 0 0
```

and you have an index

```
                     0   1
                     1   1
```

The left side of the index is which row value you increment by one and the right hand side is which columns value you increment by one.

Well the you increment the 0 row by one and the 1 row by so you get

```
                   1  1  1 
                   1  1  1
```

and then you look at the let side of the index and that means you increment the 1 column by one and the one colums by one so you get

```
                      1  2  1
                      1  2  1

                      1   3    1
                      1   3    1
```

I tried to solve this with the following code

```
 def matrix(n,m,index):

      nums=[[0]*m]*n
      print(nums)
      a=len(nums)
      b=len(nums[0])
      for i in range(a):
         c=index[i][0]
         print("the value of c is ",c)

         for j in range(b):
            nums[c][j]=nums[c][j]+1
     print(nums)
     for j in range(a):
         c=index[1][j]
         print(c)
         for i in range(a):
            nums[i][c]=nums[i][c]+1
     print(nums)


 index=[[0,1],[1,1]]
 n=2
 m=3
matrix(n,m,index)
```

but I end up getting

```
               2   6    2
              2    6    2
```

for my input

```
                0    0    0
                0    0    0
```

the weird thing is Try the same code and get the correct answer.

```
               def inc(nums):
                    print(nums)
                    a=len(nums)
                    b=len(nums[0])

                   for i in range(a):
                     c=index[i][0]
                    for j in range(b):
                         nums[c][j]=nums[c][j]+1
             print(nums)

                 for j in range(a):
                      c=index[1][j]
                      print(c)
                   for i in range(a):
                       nums[i][c]=nums[i][c]+1
             print(nums)


         a=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
         index=[[0,1],[1,1]]
           inc(a)
```

the correct answer is

```
              1   3   1
              1   3   1
```

Comment: Please fix the inconsistent indentation, both in code & data examples.

Comment: The first code block defines a function (`matrix`) that is never used.

Comment: ok let me fix it

Comment: I think it makes sense now

Comment: The first code block *still* defines a function (`matrix`) that is never used.

Comment: I call the function in the bottom the part that says                                               
       index=[[0,1],[1,1] n=2 m=3  matrix(n,m,index)

Comment: Always use 
mat = [[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]. [[0]*m]*n is a bad practice, as it creates lists with same address that might be thr mistake you've made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of instantly updating matrix, take 2 lists for row changes and column changes initialized with zero.

Traverse through index list and make changes to row and column lists:

initially

```
r = [0,0] , c = [0,0,0]
index -> 0 1
r = [1,0] , c = [0,1,0]
index -> 1 1
r = [1,1] , c = [0,2,0]
```

then, at last, you increment each row with the corresponding value in row list and same with column list.

This is an optimised solution too.

Here's my code :

```
n = 2
m = 3

index = [[0,1],[1,1]]

mat = [[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]

r = [0 for i in range(n)]
c = [0 for i in range(m)]

for ri,ci in index:
    r[ri]+=1
    c[ci]+=1

for i in range(n):
    mat[i] = [r[i]]*m

for i in range(m):
    if c[i]>0:
        for j in range(n):
            mat[j][i] += c[i]

print(mat)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3, 1],
[1, 3, 1]]
```